# Multiple definition error with 3rd party library(Qextserial) in QT

Tags: c++, qt

I am doing UI application with QT . Application will run on a desktop to get a bin file from user, and it will program a microcontroller via serial port. I have choosen "qextserialport" library for serial port communication.

I included the qextserialport header in my class like :

```
#ifndef __SERIALHELPER_H
#define __SERIALHELPER_H
#include <serialPortDriver/qextserialport.h>
#include "QThread"

class serialHelper : public QThread
{ etc.....
```

In .pro file I added this line for qextSerial

```
include(qextserialport.pri)
```

Now I am getting multiple definition error :

./debug\moc_qextserialenumerator.o: In function 'ZN20QextSerialEnumerator18qt_static_metacallEP7QObjectN11QMetaObject4CallEiPPv':

D:\QTNTloader-build-minGW-Debug/debug/moc_qextserialenumerator.cpp:47: multiple definition of 'QextSerialEnumerator::qt_static_metacall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)'

./debug\qextserialenumerator.o:D:\QTNTloader-build-minGW-Debug/../QTNTloader2/serialPortDriver//moc_qextserialenumerator.cpp:47: first defined here

Because it is my first UI program with QT I couldn't find a solution. Do you have any idea about the reason of error ?

Also now one more thing in my mind when I download qextserial I open it as project ,build it and get .moc file and added them to my project manually.I did it because I were getting a error about missing moc file , Did I do something I am not suppose to?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to add .moc files into your project manually, let qmake do that for you.
Open a Visual Studio Command Prompt (from the Start menu), go to the folder that contains your .pro file, then run:

```
qmake -tp vc
```

This should create a vcproj file that you can open in Visual Studio, containing all the files needed to compile and link.